# VB.NET checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a aspx page which contains the following CheckBoxList.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:CheckBoxList id="check1" AutoPostBack="True" TextAlign="Right" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Check" runat="server">

    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <br />
    <asp:label id="mess" runat="server"/>

</form>
```

Then in the .vb page I have a query in the Page_Load sub where I get all the customer names and whether or not they are a validated user (either true or false). When I loop through the dataset I want to add a ListItem for each name and if they are a validated user I want to have the checkbox checked. Here is my loop for the dataset

```
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        If CStr(dt.Rows(i).Item("isValid")) = True Then
            "<asp:ListItem>" + CStr(dt.Rows(i).Item("Name")) + "</asp:ListItem>" 
        Else
            "<asp:ListItem>" + CStr(dt.Rows(i).Item("Name")) + "</asp:ListItem>" 
        End If
```

I know the above loop isnt going to add the listItems, how do I add the checked ListItems in my loop? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I know there is a way to check if a box is checked such as doing

```
check1.Items(i).Selected
```

How do you check if it is not checked? Something like this?:

```
check1.Items(i).Selected = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add items to the `CheckBoxList` by using `CheckBoxList.Items.Add(ListItem)`. `ListItem` has a property [`Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.selected.aspx)  for the checked state:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim name = row.Field(Of String)("Name")
    Dim isValid = row.Field(Of Boolean)("isValid")
    Dim item = New ListItem(name)
    item.Selected = isValid
    check1.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: +1 I was about to provide my own solution until you edited yours to exactly what I would have put :)

Comment: @Curt: Yes, in m first version i've mixed up enabled with selected ;)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know VB, but in C# it would be like `check1.items.add(new ListItem("val"))` to add each `ListItem`.

Comment: Will that make a checked or unchecked box?

Comment: If you're using Dappergoat's solution then do this immediately after you add the ListItem: Check1.Items(Check1.Items.Count - 1).Checked = True/False

Comment: i dont know if you can do it in vb, but in c# you can create the listItem with attributes like this new ListItem{text = "", value ="", selected = true}. But that would just be the same as Tim Scmelters answer :)